# Performance wise in SQL Server 2012, is it the same to have a non clustered index for a char(8) field than for a bigint field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, indexing

I usually try to avoid to create indexes for non numeric fields, but in this situation I must have a non clustered index for a field that is defined as a char(8).

If I'm not mistaken the performance should be the same as having a non clustered index for a BigInt field, since they both take 8 bytes of storage. So, if the performance is the same will just create the non clustered index without changing anything, but if for some reason the performance is going to be better for a BigInt then I may consider storing the values as a BigInt instead of a char(8).

Thanks!

Comment: WTF? Why do you avoid creating such indexes? Why is your choice of data type being driven by performance over suitability?

Comment: I don't see how `BigInt` and `char(8)` would be readily interchangeable. Does the string only contain numeric characters? In that case `int` would be enough for an 8 digit number.

Comment: @DavidM well, in this case because I will need to perform lots of queries using that field and the table will have millions of rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith The values of that field will have both non unicode characters and numbers, obviously. Otherwise I wouldn't be using a char type.

Comment: So how would you store it as `bigint`? Do you mean something like `SELECT CAST(CAST('Fish' AS BINARY(8)) AS BIGINT)`?

Comment: @MartinSmith how to perform the conversion is not a problem, there are a a thousand different approaches that I could take for that. Among them I can actually perform that conversion outside the DB with virtually no efficiency impact.

Comment: Please downvoter explain why "this question does not show any research effort; it's unclear or not useful". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that `bigint` uses the same storage space as `char(8)` but might give slightly quicker performance, as the collation in use might require some conversion before the index is inserted to or searched - for example, if a case-insensitive collation is used. Whether the minimal overhead would exceed the minimal overhead of converting the values to `bigint` outside of SQL, as you suggest doing, is something that you would only be able to measure by setting up suitable test scenarios and profiling them.